# Why this output using \string on the empty csname

Tags: macros, tex-core, expansion

How does this exactly work?

```
\expandafter\string\csname\endcsname
```

I don't know what I would expect to come from there, but definitely not `\csname\endcsname_` where `_` is a space.

I thought `\csname<name of cs>\endcsname` would expand in one expansion to the control sequence `<name of cs>`. Now, I thought `\string` would print the next token, and, if it's a control sequence print `\escapechar<name of cs>`, but I'm getting something different. Where's the problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The main purpose of `\string\zzzz` is to write something to a file that when read back in produces a command token with name `zzzz`. The most general way to get the command token with name the empty string is to use `\csname\endcsname` so TeX defines `\string` to produce that if the following token is a command token with name the empty string.

Another way to get the command with empty name is to use `\` at the end of the line, this normally produces `\^^M`, as `\endlinechar` is normally 13 but if `\endlinechar` is negative or greater than 255 then no character is added to the end of the line, and in that case the same token as `\csname\endcsname` is created. This representation isn't suitable as the output for `\string` though as it only works at the end of the line, and with a non standard setting of `\endlinechar`.

Comment: My problem wasn't with the space. But as you say “that when read back in produces a command token with name…” okey, didn't now that was the behaviour of `\string`. In any case, why no space after `\csname`?

Comment: @Manuel It's just the way it is. It is hard coded into TeX the program that it produces `\csname\endcsname ` other things would have been possible but only one man can answer exactly why that exact form was chosen. Just an arbitrary choice really.

Comment: So `\csname csname\string\endcsname\endcsname` equals `\csname\endcsname` as far as `\string` or `\detokenize` is concerned.

Comment: @Manuel in the latest tex release, yes, assuming mormal catcode and escapechar settings

Comment: @Manuel Indeed: `\showtokens\expandafter{\detokenize\expandafter{\csname csname\string\endcsname\endcsname}}\showtokens\expandafter{\csname\endcsname}`

Comment: @JosephWright It's a bit misleading, though. if you define `\csname csname\string\endcsname\endcsname` and then you `\show` it followed by `\show` of `\csname\endcsname` two exact tokens seem to have different definition :)

Comment: @Manuel I was giving an example for the point you made: that from the POV of `\detokenize` the two results are the same.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You are not right. `\string\zzz X` produces `\zzzX` and, of course `\expandafter\string\csname\endcsname X` produces `\csname\endcsnameX`. The bug correction in the last version of TeX is concerned to the `\write` or `\message` output *without* usage of `\string`. For example `\message{\csname\endcsname X}` gives `\csname\endcsnameX` in TeX version 3.1415926 (and previous versions) and it gives `\csname\endcsname X` in TeX version 3.14159265.

Comment: @wipet You are of course correct. I think I must have been lead astray by the OP saying there was a space. You should never believe the OP:-) I'll fix, thanks.

Comment: @wipet second half of the answer was nonsense, I couldn't really repair it so just deleted that part.

Comment: You can get the “empty name” control sequence also in other ways.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Don't fully blame me, the `\csname\endcsname_` idea comes from you (from chat, if you remember) :P

Comment: @Manuel sorry, no one else around to blame!

Comment: @egreg sigh, the end of line trick for example. Grr I suppose I'll have to edit again:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle “Risposta esatta!” an Italian famous TV announcer would have said. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg Le mie risposte sono sempre corretti nella mia testa, è solo che a volte la mia digitazione mi delude

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Tsk, tsk. Google Translate shows its limits.

Comment: @egreg I have absolute faith